# Want to Disable Sunday in date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

Want to Disable Sunday,

```
<input id="datepicker"> var picker = new Pikaday({ 
disableDayFn: function(date)
{ 
// Disable Monday return date.getDay() === 1; 
}, field: ...
```

Comment: jQuery Datepicker - Keith Wood

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. Please read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), specifically [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - So far all I see is "I want" and a tiny amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dp").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0), ''];
    }
});
```